# statement to match truth table

Tags: logic

For the truth table

p q -

TTT

TFF

FTT

FFT

I know $p\rightarrow q$ fits this truth table (from the definition).

Is there a method to get a statement for any truth table? 
For instance, given

p q  ___

T T  T

T F  F

F T  F

F F  T

how would you go about finding a matching statement?

Comment: Trial and error, really.

Comment: You can express it as a series of ands, ors, and nots rather easily.  Whether or not it simplifies nicely is another story.  Your example though can be expressed simply as $p\wedge q$

Comment: I changed it so it's not so immediate. Thanks.

Comment: What you've given is the truth table of $p\leftrightarrow q$.

Comment: There are only 16 ways you can fill out that right-hand column. Your best bet is to start with all the "matching statements" you know and assemble a list of them. Then, you can cross-reference that list at later times. I don't think there's any general method for doing this otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly turn any truth table into a formula in
Disjunctive Normal Form.

Suppose you are given a table with $n$ columns labeled by names of variables
and one column at the far right of the table that is to be
headed by a formula expressing the truth value in that column
as a function of the truth values in the other columns.

Consider just the rows of the table on which the rightmost column has
the "true" symbol.
Write a conjunction ("and") term 
in which each of the first $n$ column headers
appears; for each "true" symbol in the first $n$ columns of that row,
include the variable at the head of that column in the conjunction,
and for each "false" symbol include the negation of the head of the column.

For example, if the headers and first row of the table look like this,
\begin{array}{ccccc}
p & q & r & s & \underline{\qquad} \\
T & F & F & T & T
\end{array}
then you write the following term:
$$ p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r \land s.$$

Now take the disjunction ("or")
of the terms for each such row of the table.
The result is a formula for the table in Disjunctive Normal form.

Here's an example with a complete table for three variables:

\begin{array}{cccc}
p & q & r & 
(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r) \lor (p \land q \land \lnot r)\\
F & F & F & F\\
F & F & T & T\\
F & T & F & F\\
F & T & T & F\\
T & F & F & F\\
T & F & T & F\\
T & T & F & T\\
T & T & T & F\\
\end{array}

Note that this does not necessarily give the most compact formula
for the truth table,
nor even the most compact Disjunctive Normal Form of the table.
Here's another example, this time for just two variables,
generated by the same procedure:
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & q & (\lnot p \land q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)\\
F & F & F\\
F & T & T\\
T & F & T\\
T & T & T\\
\end{array}

But a much simpler formula to put in the rightmost column is
$p \lor q,$
and this formula also is in Disjunctive Normal Form
(the first term is just $p$ and the second term is just $q$;
it is permissible to have a term with no $\land$ symbol if
there's only one variable in the term).
So this answer shows how to get *a* formula,
as requested,
but it does not tell you how to get the *simplest* formula.

Answer (score 3):

For $n=2\,$ variables $p$, $q$, there are totally $2^{2^n}=16$ logic functions. Each of them has a statement. Let's write down $f(p,q)$ with $(p,q)=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ in the following table and give their names.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{No.} & f(p,q) & \mbox{Statement} & \mbox{No.} & f(p,q) & \mbox{Statement}\\
\hline 1 & 0, 0, 0, 0 & 0 & 9 & 1, 0, 0, 0 & \neg p\land\neg q\\
\hline 2 & 0, 0, 0, 1 & p\land q & 10 & 1, 0, 0, 1 & p\leftrightarrow q\\
\hline 3 & 0, 0, 1, 0 & p\land\neg q & 11 & 1, 0, 1, 0 & \neg q\\
\hline 4 & 0, 0, 1, 1 & p & 12 & 1,0,1,1 & q\rightarrow p\\
\hline 5 & 0, 1, 0, 0 & \neg p\land q & 13 & 1,1,0,0 & \neg p\\
\hline 6 & 0, 1, 0, 1 & q & 14 & 1,1,0,1 & p\rightarrow q\\
\hline 7 & 0, 1, 1, 0 & p\oplus q & 15 & 1,1,1,0 &\neg p\lor\neg q\\
\hline 8 & 0, 1, 1, 1 & p\lor q & 16 & 1,1,1,1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
It just turns out each of them has a name. But as the number of variables $n$ increases, the number of logic functions $2^{2^n}$ grows quickly, and following Shannon's counting argument, a language with a vocabulary of size $a$ can only express in polynomial $P(n)$ words $a^{P(n)}\ll 2^{2^n}$ meanings. So most logic functions cannot be conveniently expressed by a concise statement. The truth table expresses the function using $2^n\gg P(n)$ numbers, which is a general way to express any logic function.